# Maven. Сборка артефактов в zip архив

Tags: maven

Имею pom.xml с двумя зависимостями, которые хочу видеть в конечном архиве, всё почти хорошо, однако при упаковке, сохраняется оригинальный артифакт, который я переименовываю и помещаю в отдельный каталог, подскажите как от него избавиться?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

POM.XML:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/ws-config</outputDirectory>
                        <includeArtifactIds>ws-config</includeArtifactIds>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>ru.croc.tn</groupId>
                                <artifactId>ear-admin-module</artifactId>
                                <type>ear</type>
                                <destFileName>ear-admin-module.ear</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/ear</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <archiveBaseDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</archiveBaseDirectory>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>${ksdd.src}/src/assembly/src.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <finalName>config-${ksdd.profile}</finalName>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.croc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ws-config</artifactId>
        <version>[0.2.5,0.3.0)</version>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.croc.tn</groupId>
        <artifactId>ear-admin-module</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <type>ear</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо использовать:maven-assembly-plugin

xxx:ear-admin-module